# Prescribed way to obtain env in hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration

Tags: environment-variables, console-application, asp.net-core-3.1

Trigger-happy duplicate closers kindly read the question thoroughly and refrain from incorrectly marking it as a duplicate.

This question is not a general question about getting the environment name. I am aware of many ways. The question is how to get a value that is guaranteed to be consistent with the value that will eventually be made available from `HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`

This question is about **console apps**. It is not about web apps, not even if you just figured out how to do this with web apps and you want to tell everyone. There is no `Startup.cs` involved. Answers that depend on the default web host fail to address the question.

The host builder setup looks like this.

```cs
      var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
      hostBuilder
      .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
      {
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
        configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "AED_COORDINATOR_");
        configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
      })
      .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder => 
      {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"{ENV_PREFIX}ENVIRONMENT");
        configurationBuilder
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appSettings.{env}.json", true, true);
      })
      ...
```

With this in `launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/aed.coordinator.dll",
      "args": [
        "--environment=Production"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "env": {
        "AED_COORDINATOR_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

running it produces this.

[image]

The problem is that `appSettings.Development.json` is loaded because `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"{ENV_PREFIX}ENVIRONMENT")` does not take into account the command line arguments.

I am aware that can extend this code to explicitly consider the command line arguments, but reliable parsing of command line arguments is non-trivial and anyway what's the point of having a builder if you have to in-line everything? Worse, they can disagree.

So, is there some way to use the builder (which is already configured in this respect) to resolve the environment?

You can't invoke `.Build()` more than once so it's not possible to partly configured the builder, construct an intermediate host, pull the resolved environment out of it and then finish configuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *possible* to do this.

```cs
      var ENV_PREFIX = "AED_COORDINATOR_";
      string env;
      using (var envHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
      {
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
        configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: ENV_PREFIX);
        configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
      }).Build())
        env = envHost.Services.GetService<IHostEnvironment>().EnvironmentName;
```

This resolves `env` in advance and properly disposes builder and intermediate host, and the rest of the code is more or less unchanged.

**However, it is not *necessary* to do it.**

In the lambda supplied to `hostBuilder.ConfigureServices()` I was inspecting the services and found that `appSettings.{env}.json` is magically added anyway — while the above code is successful, both `appSettings.json` and `appSettings.{env}.json` appeared *twice* as providers — and the host builder used the correct environment, so the entirety of

```cs
      .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
      {
        configurationBuilder
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appSettings.{env}.json", true, true);
      })
```

is unnecessary.

Which means that provided you get *this* part right

```cs
.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
{
  configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
  configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: ENV_PREFIX);
  configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
})
```

you don't need the rest.

Later code can even use the config:

```cs
      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
      {
        services.AddConfig(hostContext.Configuration);
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
      });
```

The `AddConfig` method is an extension method that prepares the options classes for use by dependency injection.

```cs
    public static IServiceCollection AddConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
      var section = config.GetSection(MosquittoOptions.SectionName);
      services.Configure<MosquittoOptions>(section);
      section = config.GetSection(ServicesLayerOptions.SectionName);
      services.Configure<ServicesLayerOptions>(section);
      return services;
    }
```